# How can I use boost::lexical_cast with folly::fbstring?

Tags: c++, boost, lexical-cast, folly

The following program:

```
#include <boost/container/string.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <folly/FBString.h>
#include <iostream>

class foo { };

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const foo&) {
  return stream << "hello world!\n";
}

int main() {
  std::cout << boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(foo{});
  std::cout << boost::lexical_cast<boost::container::string>(foo{});
  std::cout << boost::lexical_cast<folly::fbstring>(foo{});
  return 0;
}
```

gives this output:

```
hello world!
hello world!
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::bad_lexical_cast'
  what():  bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target
```

This is because `lexical_cast` doesn't realise that `fbstring` is a `string`-like type, and simply does it's usual `stream << in; stream >> out;` for the conversion.  But `operator>>` for strings stops at the first whitespace, `lexical_cast` detects that the whole input was not consumed, and throws an exception.

Is there any way to teach `lexical_cast` about `fbstring` (or, more generally, any `string`-like type)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the `lexical_cast` documentation it appears that `std::string` is explicitly the only string-like exception allowed to normal lexical-cast semantics, to keep the meaning of the cast as straightforward as possible and catch as many possible conversion errors as can be caught. The documentation also says that for other cases to use alternatives such as `std::stringstream`.

In your case I think a `to_fbstring` method would be perfect:

```
template <typename T>
fbstring to_fbstring(const T& item)
{
    std::ostringstream os;

    os << item;

    return fbstring(os.str());
}
```

Comment: Yep, looks like you're right.  The logic is buried in `boost/lexical_cast/detail/converter_lexical_streams.hpp` with no easy way to customize it.  I ended up writing own `lexical_cast` wrapper that delegates to `boost::lexical_cast` with a specialization for `fbstring`.